# Selenium eclipse maven test not executing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I am trying to execute java selenium using eclipse >> run as maven test. But my tests are not running. but the build is success. 
I am able to run using run as testng.

Here is my POM file

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.org.ccc</groupId>
  <artifactId>aa</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>aaaa</name>
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>            

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My Test Results :

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.579 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-03T12:18:19+13:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help please?

Comment: clean package install exec:java have you use this as goal?

Comment: are you using annotations for your testing?

Comment: Try with "clean test " goals should work.